# loading experience for IndexRedirect react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm wondering how the loading experience is for the [`IndexRedirect`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v3.2.6/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-redirects). In this example:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRedirect to="/welcome" />
  <Route path="welcome" component={Welcome} />
  <Route path="about" component={About} />
</Route>
```

Does it load the App component first and then redirect to the welcome path or how does it work?

Comment: I suppose the answer to your question depends on the implementation of `App` and `IndexRedirect`. Can you share a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so we can see what the code actually does? Are you really using `react-router@3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it load the App component first and then redirect to the welcome
> path or how does it work?

Actually, just took a look at the docs you linked and I'd agree with your assessment. The `App` component would be mounted and then its React subtree, i.e. its `children` prop, would be rendered. The `IndexRedirect` is the default route/redirect component so the app would be redirected to `"/welcome"` and then mount & render the `Welcome` component (*and its React subtree*).

Comment: so it loads the App component first and then redirects and loads the welcome component. Hence the loading experience would take longer since it has to load the App component in vain first?

Comment: @Tom Yeah, that order. And no, not really, `App` is mounted and rendered regardless, and remains mounted/rendered so long as the `Route` rendering on `path="/"` is still matched. The nested routes are `children` components of `App`. React is optimized to run pretty well out-of-the-box, so I wouldn't be too concerned about this performance.